# How to check if mixin was passed to the component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-test-utils

I am testing a VueJS 2 application using **vue-test-utils library** and I want to check if the **mixin was passed** to specific component, something like mounting the component using `mount` and accessing the mixin throw something like `wrapper.vm.mixins`.

I've already tried to access using: `wrapper.vm.mixin`, `wrapper.vm.mixins`, `wrapper.mixin`, `wrapper.mixins`, `wrapper.vm.$mixin` and `wrapper.vm.$mixins`.

My vue component is like this:

```
export default (Vue as VueConstructor<Vue & InstanceType<typeof MyMixin>>).extend({
  name: 'MyComponent',
  mixins: [MyMixin]
})
```

Comment: vm is current instance. If you don't have `this.mixins` when using it, there won't be `vm.mixins`.

Comment: I have it in my current vue instance.

Comment: What exactly? `mixins` property?

Comment: Yes, I improved the question to show how it is like in my code.

Comment: What is MyMixin?

Comment: It is a vue instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mixin.ts**

```html
import Vue from 'vue';

const Sum = Vue.extend({
  name: 'Sum',
  methods: {
       sum(numA: number, numB: number) {
        return numA + numB;
       }
  }
});

export { Sum };
```

**Answer 1:**

You can import the mixin in your test and check if it was passed in wrapper.vm.$options.mixins array like this:

```html
import { Sum } from './Sum'

const mixins = wrapper.vm.$options.mixins as any;

expect(mixins).toContain(Sum)
```

**Answer 2:**

You can test by the mixins names, but you need to be sure the mixin have a **name property** or it will return *undefined*:

```html
const mixins = (wrapper.vm.$options.mixins as any).map((mixin: any) => mixin.options.name)

expect(mixins).toContain('Sum');
```